# Extract an array of XML Elements from an Element

Tags: c#, json, xml

Below is my JSON that returns from an API call from a 3rd party I have to use.  I am trying to convert this to XML, then be able to get all the ViewModel elements, so I can extract them into a class (one by one), which I then save into our database.  I WAS using GetElementsById, until I noticed 'DepartmentID' is both in the ApiResult and in the ViewModel elements. The array of a class that returns in the ViewModel, is dynamic, so it is a different class for every different API call.

```
{
"ApiResult": {
    "ApiLogId": 2841360,
    "ApiLogGuid": "a783bc36-89f1-409a-a728-1f05c42231b7",
    "ApiSuccessCode": "SUCCESS",
    "ApiSuccessFlag": true,
    "ApiAuthenticatedFlag": true,
    "ApiFunctionId": 110,
    "EventId": 130305,
    "OrganizationId": 1,
    "SiteId": 3,
    "DepartmentId": 10102,
    "ScopeTypeId": 2,
    "ScopeTypeCode": "ORGANIZATION"
},
"ViewInfo": {
    "EntityType": "DbTable",
    "IsFound": true,
},
"ViewModel": [
{
    "DepartmentId": 10102,
    "DepartmentCode": "DEMO",
    "DepartmentName": "Demonstration"
},
{
    "DepartmentId": 8,
    "DepartmentCode": "SALES",
    "DepartmentName": "Sales"
},
{
    "DepartmentId": 7,
    "DepartmentCode": "HR",
    "DepartmentName": "Human Resources"
},
{
    "DepartmentId": 6,
    "DepartmentCode": "ENGR",
    "DepartmentName": "Engineering"
}
]}
```

Here is my original generic method.  I wanted to be able to pass in any class object, and extract the elements that matched the class properties.  IF the element names are unique in the XML, this method works great.  However, DepartmentId threw a wrench into my gears.

```
        public static List<T> ExtractXmltoClassList<T>(HttpResponseMessage http, string elementName) where T : new()
        {
        var ctorType = typeof(T);
        var classList = new List<T>();

        var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(http.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, "root");

        var count = doc.GetElementsByTagName(ctorType.GetProperties()[0].Name).Count;
        for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) //Itterate the number of times the tag was found (= number of elements)
        {
            var newClass = new T();

            foreach (var prop in ctorType.GetProperties())
            {
                var tags = doc.GetElementsByTagName(prop.Name);
                if (tags.Count <= 0 || tags[x].InnerText.Trim() == "")
                    continue;

                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToInt(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(long))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToLong(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToDouble(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(float))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToFloat(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToBool(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, tags[x].InnerText);
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToDateTime(tags[x].InnerText));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToGuid(tags[x].InnerText));
            }

            classList.Add(newClass);
        }
        return classList;
    }
```

Since this no longer properly works, I'd like to extract only the ViewModel element, then process it the same way I did previously.  When I originally used JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode, I thought that the root element name I was passing in, was the name of the element I wanted to start extracting at.  (my bad)

How can I achieve the same desired result?  (Please notice that my array of ViewModel objects don't have a element name to go along with them.  This is because the XML ViewModel changes on the model class it is returning from the API.

PS:  I cannot convert the JSON directly to my class object, because the 3rd party told me they make additions to their class structures often.

Comment: *I cannot convert the JSON directly to my class object, because the 3rd party told me they make additions to their class structures often.* This is not a valid reason. If the structure changes significantly, then your code will break too. If it's just adding properties, the JSON deserialisation will still succeed.

Comment: If I use the line:var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, typeof(ApiResult));

I get a null ApiResult object.

Comment: *I cannot convert the JSON directly to my class object, because the 3rd party told me they make additions to their class structures often.* -- you can use `[ExtensionData]` for this.  See [Deserialize ExtensionData](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm).  Or use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) if the JSON is completely freeform.

Comment: This also results in a blank object:  
var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Comment: Is there really no other way, using the code I provided above, to get it to work the way I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer I was looking for.  Instead of using XmlDocument, I convert to an XDocument, then get the elements inside of it.  This results in me being able to pass in any object class and class name, and returning a list of objects.

```
    public static List<T> ExtractXmltoClassList<T>(HttpResponseMessage http, string elementName) where T : new()
    {
        var ctorType = typeof(T);
        var classList = new List<T>();

        var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(http.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, "root");

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

        var count = xdoc.Descendants(elementName).Count();

        for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) //Itterate the number of times the tag was found (= number of elements)
        {
            var newClass = new T();

            foreach (var prop in ctorType.GetProperties())
            {
                var tags = xdoc.Descendants(elementName).Select(node => node.Element(prop.Name)).ToList();
                if (tags.Count <= 0 || tags[x].Value.Trim() == "")
                    continue;

                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToInt(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(long))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToLong(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToDouble(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(float))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToFloat(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToBool(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, tags[x].Value);
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToDateTime(tags[x].Value));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                    prop.SetValue(newClass, Utility.ToGuid(tags[x].Value));
            }

            classList.Add(newClass);
        }
        return classList;
    }
```